# How to change the up button colour in Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-architecture-navigation

Here is my styles code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightGrey</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightGrey</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mediumBlack</item>
</style>
```

and here is the navigation UI code

```
val myNavController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, myNavController)
```

Text changing colour works fine at style name "TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
but I want to change the colour of the upButton.
Its showing white by default, I want to change it to black.

Comment: Are you using a Toolbar or an ActionBar ?

Comment: the last line method mentioned setUpActionBarwithNavController so its ActionBar.
Here is the link for more explanation

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app theme add the `actionBarTheme` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">   
    .....
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/....</item>
</style>
```